# LINQ - Should I somehow SubmitChanges() periodically if I have a lot of changes?

Tags: c#, linq, ado.net, parallel-processing, plinq

I have a  batch of 'robots' that runs around reading RSS threads and stores the results in a database, and I parallelized it so that many feeds can be fetched at once:

```
Parallel.ForEach(context.Feeds, feed => ProcessRssFeed(feed, context));
context.SubmitChanges();
```

The 'ProcessRssFeed' function can insert records into the context as they are found, and each feed could be anywhere from zero to hundreds of items.  There are a lot of feeds, so I did not want to create a LINQ DataContext for each.

I'm worried, though, that I could be accumulating thousands upon thousands of records on the client.  I suppose I could run out of memory.

Since there's no concurrency issue here if it were possible I'd like to tell the DataContext "go ahead and submit records periodically if you like".  Is there some practical way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend creating a new `DataContext` for each. The DataContexts are quite light weight compared to the actual database connection. The `DataContext` uses connection pooling when connecting to the database, you don't get much overhead by using separate DataContexts.

Keep only the stuff that need to be submitted atomically in a DataContext, submit that and create a new DataContext for the next item.

There is no built in method for periodically submit, but you can watch the number of items in [`DataContext.GetChangeSet()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.getchangeset.aspx) and submit when that count is over a given threshold. But you should only do that if profiling shows that creating new DataContexts is really a bottleneck in your system.

Answer (score 1):

If you have many objects that have quite a bit of data, it is possible for you to start chugging up memory usage. The DataContext stores all of the tracked changes in memory until you call SubmitChanges. I would recommend measuring your program's memory usage to see if this will be an issue for you. If memory is an issue, then yes you should call SubmitChanges so the DataContext can flush some of that information out of there.

There are advantages and disadvantages to calling SubmitChanges in single call though. Let's say you really do have a lot of data and you are using a single SubmitChanges call. This will block on whatever thread it is on until its finished - and in some cases, that can be a very, very long time. This is bad if you want to do things like let the thread resume, report progress, or other side actions. In these cases you should call SubmitChanges periodically so you can let the thread resume processing other logic if it has any or needs to.

If you really don't care how long it takes, it doesn't effect anything else, then a single SubmitChanges call is fine.

In either case though, SubmitChanges still splits up each change into an individual command, and executes each command individually. So, it never does bulk or batch commands, it is always one-by-one, regardless if you make periodic calls to SubmitChanges, or a single call.

The [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb399378%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) on this will help you in understanding SubmitChanges just a bit better. There are other useful resources scattered around as well.